# How can I dynamically generate a PWA manifest in PHP pulling data from the URL and from a publicly available JSON file?

Tags: php, web, progressive-web-apps

I'm having issues setting up a Progressive Web App at the moment, here are the specifics:

## Objective:

I am trying to set up a page that will allow for the installation of multiple PWAs based on URL parameters.

To be precise, I have created a set of icons for games available on the Google Stadia cloud gaming service and would like to allow users to create desktop/home screen icons for all those titles. The games can be accessed directly by simply opening the right URL.

## Challenge

In order to allow users to have one PWA "installed" for each game/icon combo, I am trying to fill out the contents of the page with PHP.

Though I understand PWAs must be able to run client-side, it looks like as long as the initial PHP page is loaded, if the content is properly formatted and can run locally, it should be downloaded as-is and run properly; is that correct?

## Problem:

The main problem I am currently facing is that browsers seem not to recognize my `app.webmanifest` file as valid JSON, whereas when I load the page in the browser, it spits out perfectly valid PHP.

Here is the specific error in the Chrome console: `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

Here is the code that gets displayed in the "Sources" tab in the Chrome dev tools, which is **not** what the page should be generating:

*Note: I removed 3 strings that looked like uids (possibly linked to cookies?) just in case they were anything I shouldn't share.*

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>
         function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
               e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
         }

         function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
         }
         var a = toNumbers("UID_HERE"),
            b = toNumbers("UID_HERE"),
            c = toNumbers("UID_HERE");
         document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
         location.href = "MY_APP_URL/app.webmanifest?fullName=Full Name&shortName=Short&uid=b17f16d4a4f94c0a85e07f54dbdedbb6rcp1&variant=2&i=1";
      </script>
      <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
   </body>
</html>
```

## Code Breakdown:

### Context:

The PWA is being hosted on an InfinityFree web server.

***EDIT: I did find this forum post that might be linked to the error I am getting, would that make sense? https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/extra-javascript-in-response/7031/2***

*Note: I've removed any direct URL references (such as the site I am running the app off of and a github repo).*

**The main page being called is `MY_APP_URL/index.php?fullName=Full Name&shortName=Short&uid=b17f16d4a4f94c0a85e07f54dbdedbb6rcp1&variant=2`**

### Main index.php

```php
<?php
    if( !$fullName = filter_var ( $_GET['fullName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $fullName = null;
    }
    if( !$shortName = filter_var ( $_GET['shortName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $shortName = null;
    }
    if( !$uid = filter_var ( $_GET['uid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $uid = null;
    }
    if( !$variant = filter_var ( $_GET['variant'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) ) {
        $variant = 0;
    }
    if( !$alt = filter_var ( $_GET['alt'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $alt = '';
    }
    
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( "GITHUB_REPO_URL/refs.json" ) );
    
    if ($fullName != null && $shortName != null && $uid != null && $data != null)
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Game – <?php echo $fullName ?></title>
        <link rel="manifest" href="app.webmanifest?fullName=<?php
            echo $fullName . '&shortName=' . $shortName . '&uid=' . $uid;
            if ($variant != 0)
            {
                echo '&variant=' . $variant;
            }
            if ($alt != '')
            {
                echo '&alt=' . $alt;
            }
        ?>">
        <meta name="Description" content="This page will allow you to install <?php echo $fullName ?> as a Progressive Web App.">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="application-name" content="<?php echo $fullName ?>">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="<?php echo $shortName ?>">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#202124">
        <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#202124">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="https://stadia.google.com/player/<?php echo $uid ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#202124">

        <?php
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64 128x128 256x256" href="' . $data->datasets->icons->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->icons->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="' . $data->datasets->{'images-128'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-128'}->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="' . $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="' . $data->datasets->{'images-512'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-512'}->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="1024x1024" href="' . $data->datasets->images->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->images->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
            echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/webp" sizes="1024x1024" href="' . $data->datasets->webp->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->webp->extension . '">' . "\n";
            echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="' . $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->extension . '">' . "\n\t\t";
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

### The app.webmanifest File:

Note, this file is run as PHP using the following code in the folder's `.htaccess` file: `AddType application/x-httpd-php5  .webmanifest`

```json
<?php
    header('Content-Type: manifest/json');

    if( !$fullName = filter_var ( $_GET['fullName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $fullName = null;
    }
    if( !$shortName = filter_var ( $_GET['shortName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $shortName = null;
    }
    if( !$uid = filter_var ( $_GET['uid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $uid = null;
    }
    if( !$variant = filter_var ( $_GET['variant'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) ) {
        $variant = 0;
    }
    if( !$alt = filter_var ( $_GET['alt'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) {
        $alt = '';
    }
    
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( "GITHUB_REPO_URL/refs.json" ) );
    
?>{
    "name": "<?php echo $fullName ?>",
    "short_name": "<?php echo $shortName ?>",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "start_url": "https://stadia.google.com/player/<?php echo $uid ?>",
    "scope": "https://stadia.google.com/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#202124",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->{'images-128'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-128'}->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "128x128"
        },
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-192'}->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->{'images-512'}->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->{'images-512'}->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        },
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->images->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->images->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        },
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->webp->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->webp->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/webp",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        },
        {
            "src": "<?php echo $data->datasets->icons->uri . $data->uids->$uid->$variant . $alt . $data->datasets->icons->extension; ?>",
            "type": "image/x-icon",
            "sizes": "16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64 128x128 256x256"
        }
    ],
    "background_color": "#202124",
    "related_applications": [
        {
            "platform": "play",
            "id": "com.google.stadia.android",
            "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.stadia.android"
        }
    ],
    "prefer_related_applications": false
}
```

The output of this is the following:

```json
{
    "name": "Long Name",
    "short_name": "Short",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "start_url": "https://stadia.google.com/player/b17f16d4a4f94c0a85e07f54dbdedbb6rcp1",
    "scope": "https://stadia.google.com/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#202124",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/128/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "128x128"
        },
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/192/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/512/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        },
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        },
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/WebP/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.webp",
            "type": "image/webp",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        },
        {
            "src": "GITHUB_REPO_URL/Icons/The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset.ico",
            "type": "image/x-icon",
            "sizes": "16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64 128x128 256x256"
        }
    ],
    "background_color": "#202124",
    "related_applications": [
        {
            "platform": "play",
            "id": "com.google.stadia.android",
            "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.stadia.android"
        }
    ],
    "prefer_related_applications": false
}
```

### Github Repo "refs.json" file being referenced:

*I've simplified this with only one entry in `"uids"` to keep it shorter.*

```json
{
    "datasets":{
        "icons":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/Icons/",
            "extension":".ico"
        },
        "images":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/",
            "extension":".png"
        },
        "images-512":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/512/",
            "extension":".png"
        },
        "images-192":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/192/",
            "extension":".png"
        },
        "images-128":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/Images/128/",
            "extension":".png"
        },
        "webp":{
            "uri":"GITHUB_REPO_URL/WebP/",
            "extension":".webp"
        }
    },
    "other":{
        "altSuffix":"_alt"
    },
    "uids":{
        "b17f16d4a4f94c0a85e07f54dbdedbb6rcp1":{
            "0":"The Elder Scrolls – Online",
            "1":"The Elder Scrolls – Online-Morrowind",
            "2":"The Elder Scrolls – Online-Summerset",
            "3":"The Elder Scrolls – Online-Elsweyr",
            "4":"The Elder Scrolls – Online-Greymoor"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: ***SOLVED:***


It seems there was an issue with the free hosting site I was using that rendered the webmanifest unusable : https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/extra-javascript-in-response/7031/2